# How do i retrieve my own app-uri programmatically in android?

Tags: android, uri

Is there a way to get it through the context file or the package-manager? Have searched for it but didn't find anything.

Comment: What do you mean by `app uri`?

Comment: the package-name in the manifest tag.

Comment: oh, nevermind found the answer, thx for caring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call [getPackageName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName%28%29) on your context. You can call this in any Activity, Service, or basically anything that inherits from [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).

Other than that, if you want to access it somewhere without a context, just create a separate class to hold preknown values like this:

```
public class MyConstants {
    public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.my.package";
}
```

and then access it anywhere in your app using `MyConstants.PACKAGE_NAME` wherever you need it.